# Nginx and strange file permissions after upload

Tags: nginx, wordpress, php5

I am trying to upload files inside of wordpress, but I am getting errors. This is not due to the upload failing, but the upload having the wrong permissions.

I can find the uploaded file, and when I change the permissions manually with chmod ugo+r everything is fine. But by default, the file is uploaded with --w--w--w-(write access for all, but nothing else).

Anyone got a clue why this is happening? I am running nginx in a DigitalOcean machine. php 5.5.9, ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Umask 0222 is r-xr-xr-x, so Nginx should be able to read these files. What are the permissions of the root folder? Could you past the "ls -la" output before changing the permissions manually?

Comment: Sorry, I used an online tool to convert --w--w--w- So I guess the tool was wrong. Changed question accordingly.

Comment: Aaaand of course, the root directory was also missing the read flags. So that was it. Changed it and that fixed it. I probably made a mistake with changing the permissions of the parent folder.

Could you add your comment as an answer?